# UITableViewCell not showing until scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having an issue where my UITableViewCell's image (I customized it into a cell with just the image) is not showing up after being downloaded unless you have scrolled down to make it invisible and scroll up to see again.

I am using HJCache for asynchronous image downloading as well as caching. What I am not sure is if this was the issue with HJCache or my UITableViewCell and how to fix it.

Comment: If you are using blocks, this solution will work-

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17166033/2082569

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm just going to answer my own question since I had found the most ridiculous solution.

After trying out various methods and headaches, I deleted the app ( + cache) from the simulator and everything seems to be working properly again.

My best guess is that the locally stored unfinished images by HJCache were messing up.

Answer (score 1):

When the image has finished downloading (assuming the cell itself is the delegate for the asynchronous call), call [self setNeedsDisplay] which will redraw the cell. This is what happens when the cell is reloaded because of scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your data is finished loading, call `[tableView reloadData];` This will make the tableView reload all of it's cells that are currently visible.

Comment: The data is already downloaded because I can already see some cells with just the background.

Comment: Just see if calling the method I suggested fixes your problem.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't. All the views that are not visible are loaded properly.

Comment: Thanks, calling ReloadData() after binding tableView helped me.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up the cell set the image to nil. If that doesn't work set the image to a default locally stored image of the same size web if it's just completely white.